# First few cases of the Clifford algebra $\text{Cl}_{r,s}$

Tags: clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I have been reading Lawson & Michelsohn's *Spin Geometry*, and in the beginning of Chapter $1$ $\S 4$ on classification of the Clifford algebra $\text{Cl}_{r,s}$, they say that

> With little difficulty the reader can check the first few cases $$\text{Cl}_{1,0}=\mathbb C\quad\text{Cl}_{0,1}= \mathbb R \oplus\mathbb R\\\text{Cl}_{2,0}=\mathbb H\quad\text{Cl}_{0,2}=\mathbb R(2)\\\text{Cl}_{1,1}=\mathbb R(2)$$ where $\mathbb R(2)$ denotes the algebra of $2\times 2$ real matrices.

I think I understand the first three cases: for $\text{Cl}_{1,0}$, we add a basis $x_1$ such that $x_1^2=-1$ to $\text{Cl}_{0,0}=\mathbb R$, so it is $\mathbb C$ by identifying $x_1$ with $i\in\mathbb C$; for $\text{Cl}_{0,1}$, we add a basis $x_1$ such that $x_1^2=1$ to $\text{Cl}_{0,0}=\mathbb R$, so it is $\mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R$; for $\text{Cl}_{2,0}$, we add two bases $x_3,x_4$ such that $x_3^2+x_4^2=-1$ to $\text{Cl}_{1,0}=\mathbb C$, so it is $\mathbb H$ by identifying $x_3,x_4$ with $j,k\in\mathbb H$.

**Questions**: Is my understanding of the first three cases correct? How do I show the last two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\End{\mathrm{End}}
$(A note for others: OP is using the convention that $\Cl_{r,s}$
has $r$ generators squaring to $-1$ and $s$ generators squaring to $1$,
rather than the convention that seems to be more common nowadays
where $r$ and $s$ are swapped.)

For $\Cl_{2,0}$ it should be $x_3^2 = x_4^2 = -1$.
I assume this was a typo,
in which case your understanding of the first three cases is correct
so long as you recognize the importance of the fact
that the algebras are associative
and that the generators $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ anticommute.

For the last two cases I can't know what the author intended,
but a generally applicable idea is the following.

We identify vectors $V := \R^{r+s}$ as a subspace of $\Cl_{r,s}$
in such a way that $x_1,\dotsc,x_r,y_1,\dotsc,y_s$
is the standard basis of $V$.
The algebra $\Cl_{r,s}$ is generated by $V$
and inherits a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-grading where homogeneous elements
are sums of products of an even number of vectors
or sums of products of an odd number of vectors;
call these *even* and *odd* elements.
The even elements form a subalgebra $\Cl_{r,s}^+$, and we prove that
$$
  \Cl_{r-1,s} \cong \Cl_{r,s}^+ \cong \Cl_{s-1,r}
$$
(so long as $s-1 \geq 0$ or $r-1 \geq 0$).
Consider the even elements
$$
  x_2x_1^{-1},\quad x_3x_1^{-1},\quad \dotsc,\quad x_rx_1^{-1},\quad
  y_1x_1^{-1},\quad y_2x_1^{-1},\quad \dotsc,\quad y_sx_1^{-1}.
$$
They are linearly independent
since $X \mapsto Xx_1^{-1}$ is an injective linear map;
they anticommute
$$
  zx_1^{-1}z'x_1^{-1} = -zz'x_1^{-2} = z'zx_1^{-2} = -z'x_1^{-1}zx_1^{-1}
$$
(where $z, z' = x_2,\dotsc,x_r,y_1,\dotsc,y_s$ and $z \ne z'$);
they satisfy
$$
  (x_ix_1^{-1})^2 = x_ix_1^{-1}x_ix_1^{-1} = -x_i^2x_1^{-2} = -1,
$$
$$
  (y_jx_1^{-1})^2 = y_jx_1^{-1}y_jx_1^{-1} = -y_j^2x_1^{-2} = 1
$$
(where $i \ne 1$);
and their products give the standard basis for $\Cl_{r,s}^+$.
This shows that $\Cl_{r,s}^+ \cong \Cl_{r-1,s}$.
Replacing $x_1$ with $y_1$ in the above
will similarly show that $\Cl_{r,s}^+ \cong \Cl_{s-1,r}$.
Note that $y_1^{-1} = y_1$.
The use of $x_1^{-1}$ above is a convention and is not essential.

For $y_1$ we get a representation $\rho : \Cl_{r,s} \to \End_\R(\Cl_{r,s}^+)$
defined on vectors $v$ by
$$
  \rho(v)(Y) = vYy_1,\quad Y \in \Cl_{r,s}^+
$$
and on all of $\Cl_{r,s}$ by extending to a homomorphism
using its universal property.
We prefer this representation when $s > 0$.
When $s = 0$ things are trickier but this is not relevant
to $\Cl_{0,2}$ and $\Cl_{1,1}$.
This representation is injective since if $XYy_1 = 0$ for some $X \in \Cl_{r,s}$
and all $Y \in \Cl_{r,s}^+$ we simply choose invertible $Y$
and conclude $X = 0$.

Now we compare dimensions in the special case $r+s = 2$:
$$
  \dim\End_\R(\Cl_{r,s}^+) = (2^{r+s-1})^2 = 4 = 2^{r+s} = \dim\Cl_{r,s}.
$$
Thus $\rho$ is an algebra isomorphism in this case.
Finally, the existence of $\rho$ allows us to conclude
$$
  \Cl_{0,2}^+ \cong \Cl_{1,0} \cong \mathbb C
  \implies \Cl_{0,2} \cong \End_\R(\mathbb C) \cong \R(2),
$$
$$
  \Cl_{1,1}^+ \cong \Cl_{0,1} \cong \R\oplus\R
  \implies \Cl_{1,1} \cong \End_\R(\R\oplus\R) \cong \R(2).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In their book, the quadratic form on $\mathbb R^{r+s}$ is defined by $q=x_1^2+\cdots+x_r^2-x_{r+1}^2-\cdots-x_{r+s}^2$, so the quadratic form for $\text{Cl}_{2,0}$ is indeed $x_1^2+x_2^2=-1$ (which I call $x_3,x_4$), but I think it is the same when you want to find the basis by letting one of them be zero.

Comment: @DashengWang You called $x_1, x_2$ etc a "basis", so I assumed they were vectors forming an orthonormal basis generating the Clifford algebra. If you intended for them to be coordinates then saying "the quadratic form is $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = -1$" is still nonsense; the quadratic form for $\mathrm{Cl}_{2,0}$ is not equal to a constant value.

Comment: Yes, that comment was wrong, I got confused by something simple. It should be $x_3^2=-1$ and $x_4^2=-1$.

Comment: Is it true that $\text{Cl}_{0,2}=(\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R)[x,y]/(x^2=1,y^2=1)$ and $\text{Cl}_{1,1}=\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2=-1,y^2=1)$?

Comment: @DashengWang If $x$ and $y$ are commuting variables then certainly not as the resulting algebras would be commutative. If they are noncommuting then still the first I highly doubt and the second is false, as this is the same as $T(\mathbb C^2)/(e_1^2=-1,e_2^2=1)$ (a quotient of the tensor algebra with $e_1, e_2$ the standard basis of $\mathbb C^2$) which has a natural sujection onto $\mathrm{Cl}_2(\mathbb C)$; this has real dimension $2\cdot 2^2$ but $\dim\mathrm{Cl}_{1,1} = 2^2$.